# What algorithm can I use to locate bottleneck paths in an undirected graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Given an undirectional graph, how would you be able to efficiently find all of its "bottleneck" paths?

A "bottleneck" path is defined as a path that if destroyed, causes the graph to split into 2 non-connected graphs.

Algorithm for finding bottleneck paths in an undirectional graph.
Could not find such algorithm.

Comment: Check [Tarjan's algorithm for bridges in a graph](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bridge-in-a-graph/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but as a sub-problem, you can consider points in the graph such that if you remove the point it separates the graph into two or more connected subgraphs. These are called "cut vertices". Tarjan's algorithm is an algorithm for finding them.

Comment: Let's say your given out point is A. Given an cut vertex B, removing B partitions the graph into 2 or more connected subgraphs. Point A is in one of them. The next question then is where are you going? If you don't plan to leave the connected subgraph, then B was irrelevant. However, if you are considering all paths leading from vertext A, then you can easily make one of them that passes from one of the connected subgraphs into another. What I'm saying is that I think to answer your question I need more information. Hopefully based on my above thinking you understand better what's required.